# How to input titles in a aggregate(...,hist) command?

Tags: r, aggregate

I am trying to automatically create histograms with appropriate titles.

```
 a <- c('aaa','bbb','ccc','aaa','bbb','ccc','aaa',
    'bbb','ccc','aaa','bbb','ccc','aaa','bbb','ccc');
 b <- rnorm(15,0,1);
 c <- data.frame(a,b);
regions<-sort(unique(a));
```

Is there a way to input the `regions` object in my `aggregate(` command in order to do what I want?

An alternative I imagined was to use a loop and a list of dataframes using `split()` but I would like to avoid it.

Comment: So you want three histograms, one filtered by the data for each 'region'?

Comment: What is the sample output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case that you're trying to create three histograms, one for each region, appropriately titled, you could use `sapply` to avoid explicitly writing a loop.

```
# rename your data.frame c as df
colnames(df) <- c('region', 'val')
# filter your df by region, and create a title histogram
sapply(regions, function(x) hist(df[df['region'] == x, 2], main=x)
```

The result will still need some love, but this should get you started with three individually titled histograms.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ggplot solutions

```
# create more interesting example
set.seed(1)   # for reproducibility
a <- rep(c('aaa','bbb','ccc'), each=100)
b <- rnorm(length(a),mean=rep(1:3, each=100))
c <- data.frame(a,b)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(c, aes(x=b, fill=a, color=a)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=0.5, position="identity", alpha=.5)
```

[image]

```
ggplot(c, aes(x=b, fill=a)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=0.5, position="identity", color="grey70")+
  facet_grid(a~.)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
a <- c('aaa','bbb','ccc','aaa','bbb','ccc','aaa',
       'bbb','ccc','aaa','bbb','ccc','aaa','bbb','ccc');
b <- rnorm(15,0,1);
c <- aggregate(b,by=list(a),FUN=sum)
barplot(c$x, names.arg=c$Group.1,space = 0)
```

Comment: I was looking for a histogram per region, sorry if I did not express myself properly.